# call a method with the "Return" (Done) Button of the keyboard

Tags: objective-c, ios4, keyboard, return, nsuserdefaults

is there anyboby who can give me an example method that is called by pressing the return button of the keyboard and saves the text of a textview (that was typed in before) in the nsuserdefaults?

thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Make sure your `UITextField` has a return key type set to `UIReturnKeyGo` (this is for the image on the keyboard):

```
theTextField.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyGo;
```

Then use this method to do what ever you want to do:

```
- (BOOL) textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField
{
    // Tell the keyboard where to go on next / go button.
    if(textField == theTextField)
    {
        // do stuff
    }

    return YES;
}
```

To get the text from the textfield just call `theTextField.text` and save as you wish!

## Swift Version

```
func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    // Tell the keyboard where to go on next / go button.
    if textField == theTextField {
        // do stuff
    }

    return true
}
```

Comment: Why do we need the `if` statement inside this method?  Is it to check against multiple text fields within the same view controller?

Comment: If you have more than one textfield, you might want to only have it submit on the last one for example.

Comment: Remember that you need to change the keyboard style to match this however.

Comment: This post also helped by explaining a bit more about the delegate:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6190276/how-to-make-return-key-on-iphone-make-keyboard-disappear

Comment: Don't forget to hook up your controller as the delegate of the `UITextField` and implement `UITextFieldDelegate`.

Answer (score 0):

If you are adding UITextField to an UITableCell dynamically, you need to also set delegate for it:

```
    self.textfield.delegate = self;
```

also on the the header file you need to add this:

```
    @interface YourController: UIViewController <UITextFieldDelegate>
```