# How to make the keyboard disappear after clicking return button

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios5, xcode4

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to make return key on iphone make keyboard disappear?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6190276/how-to-make-return-key-on-iphone-make-keyboard-disappear)

I have two text fields in the page I'm working on. Only the first text field disappears after I click return, yet it doesn't work for the second text field.

Here are the methods in my .m file:

```
-(void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated]; 
    self.cardNameTextField.delegate = self;    
    self.pinTextField.delegate = self;
}

-(BOOL) textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField
{    
    if (_cardNameTextField !=nil)
    {
        [self.cardNameTextField resignFirstResponder];
    }
    else if (_pinTextField !=nil)
    {      
        [self.pinTextField resignFirstResponder];
    } 
    return YES;
}
```

Advice please :)

Comment: Thanks! Checking this one out.

Comment: I've lost count of how many times I've seen this question on SO. Whatever it is, `count++;`!

Comment: @tipycalFlow I don't know where to place that count ++, but thanks anyway :)

Comment: @Hans hehe...that was a joke mate! Don't worry about it...

Comment: @tipycalFlow lol, I know quite weird when I saw it. haha April fools! XD

Comment: Did you create connection for both textfields on didEnd On Exit sent events?

Comment: @Hans I've answered it anyway, with an explanation as to why you were getting it wrong and some possible solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your code was that you were checking if your `UITextField`s were `nil` or not, which aren't equal to `nil`. So whenever the conditions were checked, it always went into the first case and returned (the other being in the else). The following scenarios will also work:

```
-(BOOL) textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField
{    
    [textField resignFirstResponder];   
    return YES;
}
```

**OR**

```
-(BOOL) textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField{
 if (_cardNameTextField == textField)
 {
    [self.cardNameTextField resignFirstResponder];
 }
 else if (_pinTextField == textField)
 {      
    [self.pinTextField resignFirstResponder];
 } 
return YES;
}
```

**OR**

Just remove the `else` keyword in the second case.

**OR**

`Do it @Neelam Verma's way.`

I would recommend the first scenario which forces the first responder to be resigned without checking for any conditions...

Answer (score 5):

Replace above code with this and try if it helps:

```
-(BOOL) textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField{

    if ([_cardNameTextField isEditing]) {

    [self.pinTextField resignFirstResponder];
    }

     if ([_pinTextField isEditing]) {

    [self.cardNameTextField resignFirstResponder];

    }

    return YES;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have set the delegate of the text field.

Answer (score 0):

Use the delegate *UITextFieldDelegate*

And in your implementation class, you have two steps:

1. set the delegate

   self.textField.delegate = self;
2. implement this method

   ```
   - (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField {
      [textField resignFirstResponder];
      return YES;
   }
   ```

Comment: Thanks! :) I've done this and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

When the user taps the Done button on the text keyboard, a Did End On Exit
event will be generated, and at that time, we need to tell the text field to give up control
so that the keyboard will go away. In order to do that, we need to add an action method
to our controller class.
how about this:

in your . h :

```
- (IBAction)textFieldDoneEditing:(id)sender;
```

in your .m:

```
- (IBAction)textFieldDoneEditing:(id)sender {
[sender resignFirstResponder];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This may helps you!

```
- (void) textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *) textField
{
    [textField2 resignFirstResponder];
}
```